# How can you identify an issue with Kernelbase.dll?

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-6.0

I suspect this may not be an issue with kernelbase.dll but just how the problem is manifesting itself. I'm attempting to migrate a .net core 3.1 web service to .net 6.0. This project has a dependency on a .net468 project, which can't be migrated.

After updating the .net core app to .net 6.0 and attempting to run the web service from vs 2022 it just crashes. I checked in the event viewer > Windows > Applications and I only see 1 error (from reading other posts I should apparently also get a .NET Runtime error but never do). It simply references kernelbase.dll version 10.0.19041.1387 with an exception code of 0xe0434352. No stack trace or anything else.

Obviously when attempting to debug it fails before it even hits anything in StartUp.cs. So how can I find out what's causing this issue?

***Update***

I've been able to remove the dependency on the .NET Framework project and the web service still crashes. At the moment it's still got a reference to a .NET Standard 2.0 project, but as I understand it this is still supported. So how can I find out what's going wrong?

Comment: "I'm attempting to migrate a .net core 3.1 web service to .net 6.0. This project has a dependency on a .net468 project, which can't be migrated." - so **how** are you migrating it then?

Comment: Well at this stage, simply downloading the .net 6 sdk and changing the Target Framework to net6.0 from netcoreapp3.1 and following the migration docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: That's for migrating from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6 - I'm asking about the .NET Framework 4.6.8 project that you say "can't be migrated" but the rest of your post describes your migration work, but doesn't go into any detail about that .NET Fx 4.6.8 project.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Currently the webservice is .NET Core 3.1 and references another project (let's call it Child project) that's .NET 4.6.8. This works. Are you saying for the web service to migrate to .NET 6.0 the child project would also need to be migrated?

Comment: Yes. Loading and executing .NET Framework 4.x assemblies in .NET Core (and .NET 5 and later) is not supported. It only "works" for trivial applications making minimal use of .NET's BCL library (`System.*`). If there's a problem (and 95% of the time there will be) you'll get a `BadImageFormatException` and your process will likely crash immediately.

Comment: Why do you say the .NET 4.6.8 project cannot be migrated-over? Is it using ASP.NET WebForms or WCF or something equally horrible? If so, then that's _definitely_ the reason why it's not working. Note that you don't need the project's source-code to rebuild it for .NET Core or .NET 6: just use ILSpy or Reflector to disassemble it, then rebuild with updated references (or ideally, a clean-slate `.csproj`).

Comment: I'm going to have to just repeat what I was told at this point as I don't know the full estate of software yet. However, I believe the issue is that we have another piece of software that uses the child project and this is also on .NET Framework 4.6.8, so the child project needs to be.

Comment: If that's the case then you are simply stuck, blocked, and unable to continue (go tell your manager/client). Until and unless you can port those dependencies to (at least) .NET Standard, but preferably .NET Core, you're SOL, simply because it's impossible to safely and reliably execute .NET Framework 4.x assemblies/DLLs inside .NET Core processes. However if you can still run .NET Framework (i.e. you're not targeting Linux) then you could use IPC to communicate between the two (also, there are alternatives for ASP.NET WebForms within IIS with ASP.NET Core, e.g. ARR and Application Scopes)

Comment: @Dai Thanks. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issues, moving from 3.1 to 8.0, did the update with the VS's Upgrade tool.
This line caused the issue in the csproj:
3.1.0
It worked after removing this line.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please consider adding more context to your answer. The way it is right now, it is not clear what you mean.